# How can I verify invocation of particular parent constructor?

Tags: java, mocking, powermock

I have a code of child class -

```
public class A extends B {
    public A(User user, UserFilter filter) {
        super(user, filter);
    }

    /* the second possible option
    public A(User user, UserFilter filter) {
        super(user, filter, null);
    }
    */
}
```

And the parent class -

```
public class B {
    private User user;
    private UserFilter filter;
    private QRCode code;

    public B(User user, UserFilter filter) {
        this.user = user;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public B(User user, UserFilter filter, QRCode code) {
        this.user = user;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

I want to verify that only specific parent constructor being invoked. Not `super(user, filter, null)` but `super(user, filter)`. It's important that I can add field, so check for null for code is inappropriate.

I want to do that verification with `PowerMockito`.

Comment: So you're trying to test to make sure your `A` ctor is "correct" and nobody changes the ctor code?

Comment: I know Mocktio.verify you can do it but the object has to be mocked.

Comment: Design and test, this feels over-specified.  You can try to control your code and testing too much.  Why do you need a specific constructor?  Shouldn't the behavior of the object be enough?

Comment: @markspace Because someone after me can change my code. I want to be sure that only specific `ctor` will be invoked.

Comment: @barbara That's exactly what an over-specified test does.

Answer (score 1):

Make `public B(User user, UserFilter filter, QRCode code)` private and add static method which call it.

By doing so you will be able to instantiate your B class with any constructor. But descendants of B will be forced to use only visible constructor

Comment: It's not a solution. I just need to test the code. I can't do any refactoring stuff.